# Is it correct to use could or can?

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

May I know which is correct?

> She would travel around the world if she **could** or **can** fly like a bird.

Comment: It depends entirely on context. In a science fiction or fantasy story, some people can fly. Fly can also be used figuratively. (Such as with people using a hang glider.) The syntax is correct in both cases, and the semantics will also be correct in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

No human being can fly like a bird.

Therefore it fits the description of **Type 2 Conditional**

Therefore you should use "**could**".

Answer (score 1):

"*Can*" implies a degree of certainty that something is possible.

"*Could*" implies that something is possible, put perhaps *conditional*; or that it was only possible in the *past*.

Assuming "she" in your sentence is *not* a bird or any animal capable of flight, you are trying to suggest that flying is *not really possible*. Therefore the correct word for your sentence is "*could*".